# Initialize and Deinitialize only once with multiple threads without mutexes

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I have two functions initialize() and deinitialize() and each function should run only once. The structure is something similar to:

```
int *x;

initialize()
{
    x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
}

deinitialize()
{
    free(x);
}
```

How can I ensure that only the first thread calls initialize and only the last thread calls deinitialize.
Can this be achieve without the use of mutex?

UPDATE:
Sorry for the poor information. I am actually modifying a library that contains the functions initialize() and deinitialize(). I need to make these two functions thread-safe. The users might use multiple threads and might call these functions more than once. I cannot assume that the users will call exactly once to initialize and deinitialize functions. I can only assume is that if a thread calls initialize, it will call deinitialize at some point.

The users will be using pthread library to create their different threads.

Comment: How exactly are you starting the threads?

Comment: What is "first" and what is "last" ? Do the threads know if they are "first" or "last" ?

Comment: Did you mean `int *x;` ?

Comment: 'only the first thread calls initialize' - call it in the main thread that is started by the process loader, don't call it again.  'only the last thread calls deinitialize' - don't call that at all.

Comment: @MartinJames Or call `deinitialize` in the main thread as well after all of the threads joined.

Comment: unlesss you do it in 'main' thread or use mutex synchrnonisation, you risk concurrnet update/read of  'x' and cannot do it in any reliable way for threads running in parallel. But do you really need a single 'x' for all threads? you can have one 'x' per thread and allocate/free it inside this thread without any syncronisatin. just pass it around instead of having it global.

Comment: I am not starting the threads. The different threads will be initialize from someone else using this library. @thegreatcoder

Comment: Yes @WeatherVane

Comment: I won't be creating a main function. This is a library that needs to be modified to be thread safe.@EugeneSh.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand the problem you have. Running the function once isn't enough -- you need synchronization to ensure that threads can see all the results of the initialization function. Making this code thread safe requires providing the required visibility guarantees somehow. Shared data must be synchronized.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/call_once

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve, the most easiest is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *x;
int running;

void initialization(void)
{
    x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    puts("First thread init x");
}

void deinitialization(void)
{
    free(x);
    puts("Last thread reset x");
}


void *handler(void *data)
{
    printf("Thread started\n");
    while (running) {
      do_work();
    }
    printf("Thread exit\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t threads[3];

    initialization();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &handler, NULL);

    sleep(2);
    running = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    deinitialization();
    return 0;
}
```

Here you can be sure that your have called `init()` and `deinit()` only once.

**UPDATE**

Another variant little bit complicated, but here you also can be sure that `init()` called only once. Thread with id 0 can be start after 1 in this case we should wait while `*x` is NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 3

int *x;
int running;
int init;

struct thread_info
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int id;
    int first_id;
    int last_id;
};

void initialization(void)
{
    x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    puts("First thread init x");
    init = 1;
}

void deinitialization(void)
{
    free(x);
    puts("Last thread reset x");
}


void *handler(void *data)
{
    struct thread_info *tinfo = data;

    printf("Thread started\n");
    if (tinfo->id == 0)
        initialization();

    while (!init);
    /* EMPTY BODY */

    while (running) {
        do_work();
    }

    printf("Thread exit\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct thread_info threads[MAX_THREADS] =
    {
        [0 ... 2].id        = -1,
        [0 ... 2].first_id  = 0,
        [0 ... 2].last_id   = (MAX_THREADS - 1)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i].thread, NULL, &handler,
                      ((threads[i].id = i), &(threads[i])));

    sleep(2);
    running = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i].thread, NULL);

    deinitialization();
    return 0;
}
```

`deinit()` is a little bit tricky because your last thread can be exiting and `free(x)` while another thread is still running and maybe use it. So I leave it after all threads is exiting.

This is the point about concurrent programming. You can never make any assumptions about the order in which the threads execute.

The exact timing of when tasks in a concurrent system are executed depend on the scheduling, and tasks need not always be executed concurrently. For example, given two tasks, T1 and T2:

- T1 may be executed and finished before T2 or vice versa (serial and
  sequential)
- T1 and T2 may be executed alternately (serial and concurrent)
- T1 and T2 may be executed simultaneously at the same instant of time
  (parallel and concurrent)